# .env file variables are unable to read

Tags: javascript

my (.env file) variables are not reading in Nestjs, how do I format it in my VSC editor to execute it.      Appreciate anybody could help or advise on this. Thank you guys

```
PORT="3000"
API_PREFIX="/api/v1"

#Rabbit MQ
RABBITMQ_CONN_STRING="amqp://guest:guest@localhost:8888/"
RABBITMQ_Q_NAME="hcert-root-message"
# DB
MONGO_URL ="mongodb://localhost/jcerts-backend"

# Passport-JWT
JWT_SEC="kepler-jwt-secret"

# Mailer
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= #
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= # AWS key for SES
BASEURL= "http://localhost:3000"

# Smart Contracts

#ropsten infura
PROVIDER_HTTP= https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/63de3b382a7c4d30954ed8bf912xxxxx
INFURA_VERSION="v3"
INFURA_ID="63de3b382a7c4d30954ed8bf91xxxxx"

# OTP Required
OTP_REQUIRED_SIGN_IN = false
OTP_REQUIRED_SIGN_UP = true
OTP_REQUIRED_SIGNING = true
OTP_REQUIRED_NOAISSUE = true

# Wallet ropsten                 
WALLET_PRIV = "e70694578f637de71fc4dcd68a1d4ba418db6ebc61f9072ea52e4bxxxxxxxxx"
WALLET_ADDR = "0xEB8EaC9396267DEbe493fFc80xxxxxxxxx"

VALUE = "0.5"
GAS_PRICE_PREMIUM_PCT="10"
GAS_LIMIT="70000"
GAS_LIMIT_DOCSTORE="1500000"
ISSUEDOC_NETWORK = "ropsten"

# ropsten
DOCSTORE_FACTORY="0xb539d81F709b23D1039A19596AA19xxxxxxxxxx"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by saying "are not reading in Nestjs"? there's everything fine with .env file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click at the bottom where it says JSON

[image]

Type in env and select Environment Variables

[image]

You also need to update your env file:

- Don't use quotes
- Don't have spaces around `=`'s

If for some reason this still isn't working or Environment Variables isn't an option, install this VS Code extension:

> Name: ENV
>
> Id: irongeek.vscode-env
>
> Description: Adds formatting and syntax highlighting support for env files (.env) to Visual Studio Code
>
> Version: 0.1.0
>
> Publisher: Jakka Prihatna
>
> VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IronGeek.vscode-env

Finally, if all of this doesn't work, make sure your `.env` file is in the correct folder.

If Nestjs doesn't come with dotenv, you'll need to set it up yourself

Answer (score -1):

Check url param where i used env variable, by this way you can get and use variable value. it will help you out.

```
 var restaurants_id = 1;
    restaurants_name = "hello";
    restaurants_code = 2903483;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: ***'{{env("DB_HOST")}}',***
        data: {
            'restaurants_id': restaurants_id,
            'restaurants_name': restaurants_name,
            'restaurants_code': restaurants_code
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            
        }
    });
```